# Sping JPA. Как добавить сущность с уже существующими привязанными сущностями?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Spting JPA

У сущности Entity есть привязанная сущности BindingEntity

```
@Data
@Table(name = "entites")
@Entity
public class Entity {
...

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "binding_entity_id")
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
@ToString.Exclude
private BindingEntity bindingEntity

}

@Data
@Table(name = "binding_entites")
@Entity    
public class BindingEntity {
  @Id
  private Long id;

  private String name;
}
```

Пытаюсь создать Entity с уже существующей BindingEntity

```
public Long createEntity(EntityDto entityDto) {
        entityDto.setId(null);
        Entity entity = entityMapper.toEntity(entityDto);

        Optional<BindingEntity> bindingEntity = bindingEntityService.find(entityDto.getBindingEntityId());
        if (bindingEntity.isEmpty())
            throw new BindingEntityNotFoundException();

        entity.setBinding(bindingEntity.get());

        return entityRepository.save(entity).getId();
}

public interface EntityRepository extends JpaRepository<Entity, Long> {
}
```

В итоге вылетает "org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing

Пробовал разные ставить разные каскады: @Cascade({CascadeType....}). Результатов два:
- "org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing
- добавляются новые экземпляры BindingEntity

Как добавить сущность с уже существующими привязанными сущностями?

Comment: Разные каскады - это какие? `ALL` пробовали?

Comment: Я все возможные варианты перепробовал перечисления CascadeType. ALL добавляет новую запись привязанной сущности

Comment: А, то есть вам не нужно создавать новую запись в связи. Ок, а только `DETACH` ставили?

Comment: Все перепробовал. При DETACH org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException

Comment: Тогда покажите, ваш `BindingEntity`

Comment: Допустим там 2 поля: @Id Long id и String: name

Comment: Что значит допустим? Меня не интересуют поля, меня интересуют связи. Если вы не хотите показывать все зависимые части вашего кода, увы, здесь не гадалки...

Comment: Привел BindingEntity

Comment: А как понять `entityDto.setId(null);` и `bindingEntityService.find(entityDto.getBindingEntityId());` ?

Comment: удаляет идентификатор (если есть) и получает сущность из БД. На вход же поступает объект DTO

Comment: @MDmitry_ а можно немного больше логов, там точно написано, какая сущность неправильно создается, чтоб убедиться в правильности именно этой связи. И cascade тут не нужен, так как связанная сущность уже сохранена и получена из репозитория.

Comment: Метод `bindingEntityService.find` точно возвращает сущность BindingEntity не с пустым id ?

Comment: по-видимому createEntity должен быть @Transactional, чтобы это получилось

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, нужно сохранять не bindingEntity, но entity, в createEntity:

```
return entityRepository.save(entity).getId();
```

Comment: это была опечатка